# Was wondering how I could improve this bash script for setting up laravel directory and file permissions?

Tags: bash, file-permissions, laravel-6

Created this for file permissions for laravel, got sick of doing this in terminal.
The usergroup for httpd is apache in Fedora.
Wrote it in bash drop it in my project folder and it seems to work just fine.
Was wondering how i could make this more usable or smaller?
Or any ideas for it.

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ -f artisan ]; then
    sudo chown -R $USER:apache $PWD
    sudo find $PWD -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
    sudo find $PWD -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
    sudo chgrp -R apache storage bootstrap/cache
    sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
    echo "file permissions all set"
else
    echo 'Artisan command does not exist are you in the laravel installation base directory';
fi
```

Comment: Problem is that with sudo you've to enter your password otherwise without sudo directory permissions can be changed but not for files.

Comment: The last `echo` should be two sentences. The second one starts with `Are you` and is a question, and thus should end with a question mark.

Comment: Rather than all the `find ... -type ... chmod` stuff, just use `chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX .` -- the `X` symbolic permission means "execute, if it makes sense" which generally means on directories but not files. (And `.` refers to the current directory; simpler than `$PWD`.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Laravel's [Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/envoy) for running specific tasks like these? First, install Envoy globally.

```
composer global require laravel/envoy
```

Then create a file called Envoy.blade.php in the root directory.

**Envoy.blade.php**

```
@setup
    $chmods = [
        'storage',
        'bootstrap/cache',
    ];
@endsetup

@servers(['local' => '127.0.0.1'])

@story('deploy')
    permissions
    finishDeploy
@endstory

@task('permissions')
    @foreach($chmods as $file)
        chmod -R 755 {{ $file }}
        chmod -R g+s {{ $file }}
        chown -R apache:apache {{ $file }};
        echo "Permissions have been set for {{ $file }}."
    @endforeach
    echo "File permissions complete."
@endtask

@task('finishDeploy')
    echo 'Deployment finished successfully!'
@endtask
```

In Terminal, you can get this to run with the following command.

```
envoy run deploy
```

Comment: nice willl check it out